# How to set an element style :focus without style :hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, focus

Please tell me whether it is possible to use style :focus without style :hover, i.e. when the element is not selected and the mouse cursor is moved to it, then the style :hover is applied, and when the element is selected and the mouse cursor is hovered, the style :hover is not applied?

For example:

```
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

input:hover {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

New maybe:

```
input:focus:not[':hover'] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

input:hover {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried switching those rules around to take advantage of the simple cascade order of CSS? e.g: declare `input:hover` rule first, then declare `input:focus` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using `:not` selector easily.here is detail about [:not selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

```
input:focus:not(:hover) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input:hover {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try the below example

NB:It's just a sample you can change as per your needs.

```css
a:hover:not(:focus) {
  color: default;
}

a:focus {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">Test!</a>
```